# Triggering Javascript using a variable

Tags: javascript

I have a external JavaScript file that I want to run when the value of an externally derived variable called 'trigger' is equal to 1. Below is the start of the code. As you can see the code was started by an eventListener (line 5) I had hoped it would be as simple as using an if statement but that was wishful thinking!

I'm still pretty green on JavaScript, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(function() { 
    if (trigger = 1) {
        var time=5000;
        var colourchange = document.getElementById("window");
        //colourchange.addEventListener("dblclick", transition, false);

       function transition() {

           if (this.className == "transparent") {
               this.className = "black";
           } else if (this.className == "black") {
               this.className = "transparent"; }
```

Comment: `trigger = 1` assigns value `1` to `trigger`.. you're probably looking for `trigger == 1`

Comment: Are you trying to run the script each time the value 1 is assigned to trigger?

Comment: Merlin - yes I am. BeNdErR and andrew have just pointed out that my if should be trigger==1 not trigger=1. I knew that so I'm suitably embarrassed.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
 if (trigger == 1)
```

`=` is an assignment operator,
 `==` is a comparator

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Comment: Many thanks. I knew that so I'm feeling stupid. I'll try it soon.